# HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths not working since 1709

Tags: windows

All of our applications have stop working after the the WIN 10 Ver 1709 update.

The failure is `dll not found`

I have determined that the *path* subkey under 
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\xxx.exe` is no longer 
being applied to the system path used to start the application.

Just to be clear:

> 1. Our typical target machine is Win 10 home.
> 2. All of our software is installed and functional.
> 3. The WIN 10 Update 1709 is installed.
> 4. All of our software stops working.

Altering the system PATH env var to include only our paths fixes the problem.
But this is not a solution (due to DLL clashes in other installed software)!

Creating a bat file that sets the path to our paths before calling our 
executable also works. NOTE: This is essentially what the App Paths path is 
supposed to do.

Does anyone have a clue what has changed in how the 
 `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` is implemented?

A typical entry under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` looks like this:

> Key:*app.exe*
>
> > SubKey: (Default) --- Value: [full path]\app.exe
> >     SubKey: Path -------- Value: [full path to directory];[full path to directory];

The Path value is just like the System Path env var

But realize that the existing registry entry and our code does not change when the WIN update is done.

A BAT file with:

`Set PATH=[full path to directory];[full path to directory];%PATH%
[full path]\app.exe`
is all that is necessary to successfully execute app.exe

This is what leads me to suspect that the problem is in the *App Paths* implementation.
Since Microsoft strongly suggests using *App Paths*, I find it unusual that no one but me is experiencing this failure.

Comment: Do you put anything special in the registered path? Like, environment variables or anything of this sort? Could you provide an example of such path?

Comment: I doubt it hasn't been working since 1709. In fact, IIRC, I used app paths quite a lot just a few years ago. (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: Well then, Andreas, please explain the observation that prior to the update everything runs and after the update everything  fails to find DLL's. 
Our installed code did not change nor did the registry settings for our app paths. 

If you really "used app paths quite a lot" please enlighten me.

Comment: Just saying that you doubt my observation is not helpful. 
What would you suggest might be a reason for this behavior?
Is there now a new requirement for registering applications?

Comment: Try figuring out where SnippingTool.exe is located. Explorer and cmd.exe seem to indicate it's at c:\windows\system32, but you can't pick it there in a file dialog, and Everything (an NTFS file system parser) does not think the file is located there. It's very bizarre. You also can't launch SnippingTool.exe from location's where it's actually found (i.e. by Everything), and just get a blank error dialog; but if the app is already running, it will transfer focus to the app, so there's some bug in how it's being launched.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with Win 10 1709 in which the path entry of the app paths is restricted to about 250 characters in length.  If your path entry is below this threshold, it is applied as expected to the environment of the application.  Otherwise, it is just discarded.
I have not found any information from Microsoft acknowledging this as a bug, but this is our observation.
We have resolved the issue by doing one of the following:
* If possible, reduce the size of your path string by using short paths and be sure the path includes only what is really necessary.
* If the path is still too long, then we use a bootstrapper that we created to first apply the path to the process environment and then launch the desired executable.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for this acknowledgment.  I have finally come to the same conclusion just today (in fact) after a lot of trial and error. As I told my colleagues, Microsoft will just say that they have closed a hole rather than introduced a bug. My investigation yielded several guesses as to the maximum length of the path (most around 260) however, Microsoft states that keys are limited to 260 but values are >16000. 
Anyway, I am in agreement that my paths must be shortened and extended in the process as necessary at run time (for plugins, etc).